# How do I install tor on arch in a country where tor is blocked?

Tags: blocked-services

I'm trying to install tor in a country (UAE) where it's blocked. I get an error presumably because it's blocked here:

```
:: Checking for conflicts...
:: Checking for inner conflicts...
[Aur: 1]  tor-browser-8.5.5-1

  1 tor-browser                              (Build Files Exist)
==> Packages to cleanBuild?
==> [N]one [A]ll [Ab]ort [I]nstalled [No]tInstalled or (1 2 3, 1-3, ^4)
==> 
:: PKGBUILD up to date, Skipping (1/1): tor-browser
  1 tor-browser                              (Build Files Exist)
==> Diffs to show?
==> [N]one [A]ll [Ab]ort [I]nstalled [No]tInstalled or (1 2 3, 1-3, ^4)
==> 
:: Parsing SRCINFO (1/1): tor-browser
==> Making package: tor-browser 8.5.5-1 (Mon Oct 14 17:01:56 2019)
==> Retrieving sources...
  -> Found tor-browser.desktop
  -> Found tor-browser.png
  -> Found tor-browser.sh
  -> Downloading tor-browser-linux64-8.5.5_en-US.tar.xz...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to dist.torproject.org:443 
==> ERROR: Failure while downloading https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/8.5.5/tor-browser-linux64-8.5.5_en-US.tar.xz
    Aborting...
Error downloading sources: tor-browser
```

Someone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget using AUR for this because AUR will only download from one specific place unless you recode it to pull from another location yourself. Download Tor Browser from another source.  I am going to copy and paste the entire page from the Tor Project since you probably can't read it yourself from UAE

> The safest and simplest way to download Tor Browser is
>   from the official Tor Project website at
>   https://www.torproject.org/download. Your connection to the site will
>   be secured using HTTPS, which makes it much harder for somebody to
>   tamper with.
>
> However, there may be times when you cannot access the Tor Project
>   website: for example, it could be blocked on your network. If this
>   happens, you can use one of the alternative download methods listed
>   below.
>
> MIRRORS If you're unable to download Tor Browser from the official Tor
>   Project website, you can instead try downloading it from one of our
>   official mirrors, either through [EFF](https://tor.eff.org/) or [Calyx Institute](https://tor.calyxinstitute.org/).
>
> GETTOR GetTor is a service that automatically responds to messages
>   with links to the latest version of Tor Browser, hosted at a variety
>   of locations, such as Dropbox, Google Drive and GitHub.
>
> TO USE GETTOR VIA EMAIL: Send an email to gettor@torproject.org, and
>   in the body of the message simply write “windows”, “osx”, or “linux”,
>   (without quotation marks) depending on your operating system.
>
> GetTor will respond with an email containing links from which you can
>   download the Tor Browser package, the cryptographic signature (needed
>   for verifying the download), the fingerprint of the key used to make
>   the signature, and the package’s checksum. You may be offered a choice
>   of “32-bit” or “64-bit” software: this depends on the model of the
>   computer you are using.

Comment: You're right I can't read that page in the UAE. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With arch you can install torsocks then install tor-browser from aur like this

```
sudo pacman -S community/torsocks
```

```
torify yay -S aur/tor-browser
```